# Can't make a POST request to the Spring Boot server

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, cors

I'm making a Spring Boot application that has a controller. The application is running on a domain, when I try to make a POST request via a link via http, I get a 405 error, but when making a request via https everything works, the strangest thing is that it doesn't matter for the GET method http or https, it works in both cases. Below is the code of the controller and an example of requests.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Tag(name = "Quiz")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/quiz")
public class QuizController {

    private final QuizService quizService;

    @Operation(
            description = "Creating quiz",
            summary = "Creating new quiz by dto and sending message to users",
            responses = {
                    @ApiResponse(description = "Success", responseCode = "201"),
                    @ApiResponse(description = "Quiz with this name already exists", responseCode = "400")})
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public void createQuiz(@RequestBody QuizDataDTO quizDataDTO) {
        quizService.createQuiz(quizDataDTO);
        quizService.spreadQuiz(quizDataDTO.getTelegramUsersIds());
        log.info("Create quiz with name {}", quizDataDTO.getQuizDTO().getQuizName());
    }

    @Operation(description = "Get links",
            summary = "Getting all links from google sheets lists",
            responses = @ApiResponse(description = "Success", responseCode = "200"))
    @GetMapping("/links")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<QuizDetailsDTO> getAllQuizs() {
        log.info("Return all quiz");
        return quizService.getAllQuizs();
    }
}
```

[Use POST to http](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iCbH.png)

I tried to configure CORS in configuration file. It doen't works

Comment: what is this has to do with [tag:cors]?

Comment: Can you please share a [mcve] so we can test it ourselves?

Comment: @dan1st I think not because the application is running on a server that can only be accessed via vpn

Comment: The strangest thing is making a request over https everything works, but if you try to make a request over http, you will get a 405 error

Comment: Did you define a context path? If not, you should do It. Then your uri will become "http://[server-domain]/[context-path]/api/quizz"
Follow this tutorial to define the context path:  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-context-path

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Bean, I Hope Working That For You

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/greeting-javaconfig").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I added such a configuration class, it didn't help

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowedHeaders("*");
    }
}
```